# Changing default WP-Site creation date

Tags: posts, date, date-time

I started creating WP-Site this `January-2015` but as per my project `I need to include posts which are from year 2007` I created posts with the required date now I used a calender which sorts posts when we select required date in it.Now my problem is that calender only showing this January in it and not going beyond that I came to know it is going only upto my creating date of my site not showing beyond that date now is there any possibility to `change my WP-Site creating date` please help me with this so that I can make my calender to show previous years date too.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please specify "I used a calendar which sorts posts". What kind of calendar is this? A plugin?

Comment: You can change it with MySQL if you really want, but I'd be surprised if it would make a difference.

Comment: @DavidGard can you please help me with the table in which I should edit this.

Comment: @jzatt it is a default calendar widget.

Answer (score 2):

There is no blog creation date in Wordpress. The first blog post is usually regarded as the blog creation date when you create copyright footer notes for a blog. This is not very reliable though.

There are a few thing that happens by default when Wordpress is first installed, the most important being a user is created with ID `1`. This is the most accurate way to determine when a blog was created. User 1 is usually the admin or super admin and is not normally deleted, so the user registration date for user `1` is sometimes used to determine blog creation.

Apart from that, Wordpress self does not save a date when it was first installed. So your problem is definitely not this. The only dates that really play a big role when it comes to posts is the post date and the post gmt date. Calenders, by default, uses either of ther two dates to display posts according to calender. Some custom ones can use dates set by custom fields, but this is usaully done on site by the site owner

I would suggest that you have alook at both your post dates and post gmt dates and make sure they are correct. I really doubt that any calender scripts out there uses the user registration date as a referrence, but just in case, if your dates are correct, change the `user_registered` date of user `1` in the [`wp_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) table.

If this don't work, download a database optimizer plugin and run that on your database and check for any errors